# DNS: cname wildcard entry subdomain with hyphen

Tags: ssl, subdomain, cname-record, wildcard

I am trying to make a wildcard cname entry on my dns provider as follows:
*-abc.[domain].com or even *abc.[domain].com but it does no work.

If i do *.abc.[domain].com then it will work but I don't want to use dot.
I am using hyphens as opposed to dots as I have a wildcard SSL certificate so all "levels" are covered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not going to work. A wildcard must cover a whole "domain level", you can't use it to match parts of a domain. See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_DNS_record) and [RFC 1034](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1034).